# Using Beautiful Soup for a simple stock price tracker

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to make a stock price tracker bot but the website has a code like this:

```
        <div class="kurBox">
        <span class="text">ALIŞ(TL)</span>
        <span class="value up">7,8175</span>
    </div>
    <div class="kurBox">
        <span class="text">SATIŞ(TL)</span>
        <span class="value up">7,8240</span>
```

I need to get the value of both these lines after the texts. And when value now goes below the starting value of today, class changes to value down.

Here is a part of the code I use, the code works does almost everything I want but it doesn't extract both values at the same time and sometimes values mix up when one of their class changes to value down. How can I solve this issues?

```
url = "http://bigpara.hurriyet.com.tr/doviz/dolar/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml-xml")
old_value = soup.find("span" ,attrs={"class":"value up"}).text
first_value = soup.find("span" ,attrs={"class":"value up"}).text
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(" ")
print("******************************************")
print("|", current_time, "|", "Doların ilk fiyatı: ", first_value, "|")
print("******************************************")
print(" ")
print(" ")


bakiye = round(float(100.0000), 4)
dolar = int(0)
hold = time.sleep(0)

while True:
 time.sleep(1)
 url = "http://bigpara.hurriyet.com.tr/doviz/dolar/"
 response = requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml-xml")
 new_value = soup.find("span" ,attrs={"class":"value up"}).text
```

Comment: probably you need `find_all` instead of `find` - to get list with all items.

Comment: Number `0` (zero) is already integer value and there is no need to use `int()` - `dolar = 0`. Number `100.0000` is already float value and there is no need ot use `float()` - and it is rounded to 4 places so there is no need to use `round()` - `bakiye = 100.0000`. And `sleep(0)` makes no sense.

Comment: @furas Idk it was giving error so I tried to specify them and it worked. Maybe it needs to be specified for the rest of the code. And `find_all` result as: `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?` and if I delete `.text` it prints the whole line `<span class="value up">7,8288</span>, <span class="value up">7,8345</span>`

Comment: as I said in previous comment - `find_all` gives **LIST** with all items. And when you have list then you have to use `for`-loop to work with every item separatelly and get `.text` separatelly - ie. `for item in list: print(item.text)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `.find_all()` as suggested. To deal with if the class attribute changes from `value up`, to `value down`, you can use regex to get the elements that have a class that contains `value`. That will get wither one then.

Not sure exactly you want the output, but this should get you going:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import re


url = "http://bigpara.hurriyet.com.tr/doviz/dolar/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml-xml")

values_list = []
values = soup.find_all('span',{re.compile('value')})
for val in values:
    text = val.find_previous('span').text
    value = val.text
    values_list.append((text,value))
    
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(" ")
print("******************************************")
print("|", current_time, "|", "Doların ilk fiyatı: ", values_list[0][1], "|")
print("******************************************")
print(" ")
print(" ")

print ('Second value: ', values_list[1][1])
```

**Output:**

```
******************************************
| 11:14:46 | Doların ilk fiyatı:  7,8240 |
******************************************
 
 
Second value:  7,8279
```